# ServerSocketChannel to accept more connections from the same client

Tags: java, sockets, serversocket, server, socketchannel

my server needs to accept new connections from the same client. Because my client do relogin after 10 hours connected. It is a server/client for iscsi protocol and my client is a microsoft iscsi initiator.

So I would like a sugestion. Today I have a thread pool with size 4, so my server can accept 4 relogins from the same client. But this number could increment as my time connected is big. The code is below.... Should I terminate the threadPool and submit the connection again? It is the better approach?

thanks in advance.

```
ExecutorService threadPool = Executors.newFixedThreadPool(4);
        // Create a blocking server socket and check for connections
        try {
            // Create a blocking server socket channel on the specified/default port
            System.out.println("0");
            serverSocketChannel = ServerSocketChannel.open();

            // Making sure the socket is bound to the address used in the config.
            serverSocketChannel.socket().bind(
                    new InetSocketAddress(getConfig().getTargetAddress(), getConfig().getPort()));
            System.out.println("0.1");

            serverSocketChannel.configureBlocking(true);
            System.out.println("0.2");

            System.out.println("1");

            while (running) {
                System.out.println("2");

                // Accept the connection request.
                // If serverSocketChannel is blocking, this method blocks.
                // The returned channel is in blocking mode.
                final SocketChannel socketChannel = serverSocketChannel.accept();
                System.out.println("3");

                // deactivate Nagle algorithm
                socketChannel.socket().setTcpNoDelay(true);

                connection = new TargetConnection(socketChannel, true);
                System.out.println("4 - ");
                try {
                    final ProtocolDataUnit pdu = connection.receivePdu();
                    // confirm OpCode
                    if (pdu.getBasicHeaderSegment().getOpCode() != OperationCode.LOGIN_REQUEST)
                        throw new InternetSCSIException();
                    // get initiatorSessionID
                    LoginRequestParser parser = (LoginRequestParser) pdu.getBasicHeaderSegment().getParser();
                    ISID initiatorSessionID = parser.getInitiatorSessionID();

                    /*
                     * TODO get (new or existing) session based on TSIH But since we don't do session reinstatement and
                     * MaxConnections=1, we can just create a new one.
                     */
                    TargetSession session = new TargetSession(this, connection, initiatorSessionID,
                            parser.getCommandSequenceNumber(), parser.getExpectedStatusSequenceNumber());
                    // set ExpCmdSN (PDU is immediate, hence no ++)

                    sessions.add(session);
                    System.out.println("5 - sessions.size(): " + sessions.size());
                    threadPool.submit(connection);// ignore returned Future
                    // connection.call();
                } catch (DigestException | InternetSCSIException | SettingsException e) {
                    System.out.println("TargetServer: "
                            + new ToStringBuilder(sessions).reflectionToString(sessions).toString());
                    LOGGER.info("Throws Exception", e);
                    continue;
                }
            }
```